# Slick slider doesnt work when the content is created with loop

Tags: javascript, slick.js, tabletop.js

I'm trying to load data from Google spreadsheets and loop the data with javascript. This is the code that works perfectly where the data is hardcoded in Html.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Responsive history timeline</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <!--Timeline carousel-->

    <section class="timeline-carousel">
        <h1>History timeline</h1>

        <div class="timeline-carousel__item-wrapper"data-js="timeline-carousel">
            <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                    <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('https://www.historyonthenet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/135151-004-0D4D550E.jpg') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <span class="year">1914</span>
                    <span class="month">June 28</span>
                    <p>Assassination of Archduke Franz Ferdinand of Austria, heir to the Austro-Hungarian throne, who was killed in Sarajevo along with his wife Duchess Sophie by Bosnian Serb Gavrilo Princip.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->

            <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                    <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('http://factsforkids.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/13.jpg') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <div class="pointer"></div>
                    <span class="month">July 5  </span>
                    <p>Austria-Hungary seeks German support for a war against Serbia in case of Russian militarism. Germany gives assurances of support.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->

           <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                    <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*tjpdoOeFp6PfczMjqh6JEA.jpeg') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <span class="year">1915</span>
                    <span class="month">January 2</span>
                    <p>The Russian offensive in the Carpathians begins. It will continue until April 12.    </p>
                  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->

           <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                    <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/media/images/72349000/jpg/_72349652_generals-on-horseback.jpg') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <div class="pointer"></div>
                    <span class="month">January 18–19   </span>
                    <p>Battle of Jassin.    </p>
                  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->

           <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                    <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/world-war-1-photography-30.jpg?quality=85&strip=info&w=550') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <span class="year">1916</span>
                    <span class="month">January 5–17</span>
                    <p>Austro-Hungarian offensive against Montenegro, which capitulates.    </p>
                  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->

           <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                    <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('https://kidskonnect.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Approaching_Omaha.jpg') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <div class="pointer"></div>
                    <span class="month">January 6–7 </span>
                    <p>Battle of Mojkovac.  </p>
                  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->
           <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                    <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('https://www.trimart.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/1970/01/GREEN-APPLE-1-PIECE.jpg') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <div class="pointer"></div>
                    <span class="month">2019</span>
                    <p>Green apple</p>
                  <a href="https://www.trimart.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/1970/01/GREEN-APPLE-1-PIECE.jpg" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->
           <!--Timeline item-->
            <div class="timeline-carousel__item">
                <div class="timeline-carousel__image">
                <div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5849b12a2e69cf47aecece6b/584ebb9646c3c416aac4f2b5/5d50528ce6bf0300010ffed8/1565554761086/red-apple-small.jpg?format=2500w') center center; background-size:cover;"></div>

                <div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                    <div class="pointer"></div>
                    <span class="month">2018</span>
                    <p>Apple</p>
                  <a href="https://static.agcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2018/11/apple_GettyImages186843005_cmyk.jpg" class="read-more">Read more</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--/Timeline item-->

        </div>

    </section>
    <!--Timeline carousel-->

    <!-- partial -->
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.5.1/tabletop.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'>    
      var publicSpreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1znAku0PXH31_0hH-z3b86DMBf_4jr7JBe4BDuuaDGTw/edit#gid=0';

      function init() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
                         callback: showInfo,
                         simpleSheet: true } )
      }

      function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        alert('Successfully processed!')
        console.log(data);
      }

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
      </script>

      <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js'></script>
      <script  src="./script.js"></script>
      <!--<script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>-->

    </body>
    </html>
```

**script.js**

```
$.js = function (el) {
    return $('[data-js=' + el + ']')
};

function carousel() {
  $.js('timeline-carousel').slick({
    //centerPadding: '60px',
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    dots: true,
    //speed: 500,
    //centerMode: true,
    //touchThreshold : 2,
    arrows: true,   
    /*autoplay: false,     
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 800,
        settings: {

          centerPadding:'40px',
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 800,
        settings: {

            centerPadding:'40px'
        }
      }
      ]*/
  });
}

carousel();
```

The code above is working fine. But when I try to load the data from a spreadsheet through `tabletop.js` and using Javascript to loop through the data, the slick slider doesn't work. Below will paste the code where I code to load data from spreadsheet and using a javascript loop.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Responsive history timeline</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!--Timeline carousel-->
<div class="timeline-carousel">
    <h1>History Timeline</h1>
    <div class="timeline-carousel__item-wrapper" data-js="timeline-carousel">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.5.1/tabletop.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>    
  var publicSpreadsheetUrl = '1znAku0PXH31_0hH-z3b86DMBf_4jr7JBe4BDuuaDGTw';

  function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
                     callback: showInfo,
                     simpleSheet: true } )
  }

  function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    /*alert('Successfully processed!')*/
    console.log(data);
    for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
    $('.timeline-carousel').append(     
        '<div class="timeline-carousel__item">'
        + '<div class="timeline-carousel__image">'
        + '<div class="media-wrapper media-wrapper--overlay" style="background: url(' + data[i].photo + ') center center; background-size:cover;"></div></div>'
        + '<div class="timeline-carousel__item-inner">'
        + '<span class="year">' + data[i].year + '</span>'
        + '<span class="month">' + data[i].month + '</span>'
        + '<p>' + data[i].caption + '</p>'
        + '<a href =' + data[i].link + ' class="read-more">Read more</a></div></div>');     
    }    
  }  
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
  </script>

  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
 $.js = function (el) {
    return $('[data-js=' + el + ']')
};

function carousel() {
  $.js('timeline-carousel').slick({
    //centerPadding: '60px',
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    dots: true,
    //speed: 500,
    //centerMode: true,
    //touchThreshold : 2,
    arrows: true,   
    /*autoplay: false,     
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 800,
        settings: {

          centerPadding:'40px',
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 800,
        settings: {

            centerPadding:'40px'
        }
      }
      ]*/
  });
}

carousel();
```

Hope to find a solution here thank you and appreciated...

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Do you re-initialise the slider for the newly added elements? You can't just append items, you have to destroy the slider, add some items and then init it again (If I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I mean the below version doesnt work like the hardcoded version. Thanks for your advice I'll search some documentation about what you say.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), you see (under `Add & Remove`, sadly there is no way to directly link to a section) that there is a predefined way of dynamically adding (and removing) slides:

```
$('.add-remove').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
$('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>I'm a new slide!</h3></div>');
```

This code adds a card to the `add-remove` slider. So don't use `append`, use `slickAdd` (and no need to destroy and reinit the slider)